# Couldn't Insert Values into Database

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I Have Created Registration Jsp and Servlet.When I Insert the Values Using Form,Values not inserted as well as Some Exception come on Apache Log.Can any one Help me to Find actual Error.in my query or Connection????

```
Jul 27, 2012 9:00:30 PM com.asiahospital.db.DataPersistor registerUser
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2618)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2568)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:842)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:681)
    at com.example.db.DataPersistor.registerUser(DataPersistor.java:29)
    at com.example.servlet.RegistrationServlet.doPost(RegistrationServlet.java:40)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at [...]
```

The offending method:

```
public void registerUser(User user) { 
    try { 
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
        String query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('" + user.getUserName()+ "','" 
            + user.getPassword() + "','" + user.getFirstName() + "','"
            + user.getLastName() + "','" + user.getEmail() + "','false')"; 
        stmt.execute(query); 
    } catch (SQLException ex) { 
        Logger.getLogger(DataPersistor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Post the SQL query that is being executed, and the definition(s) of the relevant database table(s).

Comment: Let's see the code in the `registerUser` method

Comment: public void registerUser(User user) {
        try {
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            String query = "INSERT INTO user VALUES ('" +user.getUserName()+ "','" + user.getPassword() + "','" + user.getFirstName() + "','" + user.getLastName() + "','" + user.getEmail() + "','false')";
            stmt.execute(query);



        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataPersistor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }




    }

Comment: and also use preparesStatements instead of string query concatination as this is subject for **sql injections**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your insert statement, the number of columns you have supplied is not the same as the number of values you specified.

e.g.

insert into Table 1 (A, B, C) values (100, 1001, 1002, 1004).

=> 3 columns != 4 Values.

Answer (score 2):

It is very likely that your query looks something like this:

```
INSERT INTO my_table(A, B, C) VALUES ('a', 'b')
```

Or like this (where my_table still has three columns)

```
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ('a', 'b')
```

Quite obviously, that won't work, as you'll have to provide as many values as columns. From your comments, I suspect it's the second case. You had a pre-existing SQL statement and someone has added / removed a column from your `user` table, rendering this SQL statement invalid

Comment: This is why I always specify `INSERT INTO table(field1,field2,field3) values(foo,bar,baz)` - when I make a schema change, nothing breaks. If I needed that extra field on the insert, it would get found during testing quite easily - often, you don't need to add that field everywhere.